# :Before content without border

Tags: html, css

I would like to cancel border next to colored text `EXAMPLE`. I tried to set `border: none`, but it doesn't work. Is here some workaround?
Here is my code:

```css
div.example {
  font-size: 1em;
  /*letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 line-height: 1.5em;*/
  border: 0px;
  border-left: 4px solid #64c6ed;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.example::before {
  content: 'Example';
  color: #64c6ed;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*line-height: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 0.3em;*/
  border: 0px none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <p>Popis položek, který je uveden u mzdových listů souhrnných (MLS), může vypadat např. takto:<br />&#160;
    <table class="B1-P4">
      <tr>
        <th class="seda">Název</th>
        <th class="seda">Popis </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="seda">SP základ celkem<br /><span class="FieldName">S_SocialInsBase</span></td>
        <td class="seda">Počítaná položka. Celkový základ SP vypočtený ze základů SP pro jednotlivé prac. poměry daného zaměstnance <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>......atd.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Tj. na nějakém vstupním formuláři souhrnného mzdového listu je položka "SP základ celkem". V programu je definována pod názvem <i>S_SocialInsBase</i> (a pod tímto názvem ji lze i vyhledat v programu i v helpu). Popis se odkazuje na položku dílčího
      mzdového listu "Základ SP" <i>(S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>. Jelikož se jedná o položku jiné agendy (jiného Business objektu), je uvedena i její zkratka, aby nedošlo k záměně, tj. <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

The border is part of the `.example` div, and you can't remove by changing the pseudo element. You can place the `::before` element outside of the div by using `position: absolute`:

```css
div.example {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
  /*letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 line-height: 1.5em;*/
  border: 0px;
  border-left: 4px solid #64c6ed;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 8px;
  margin: 25px 0 15px;
}

div.example::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  content: 'Example';
  color: #64c6ed;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*line-height: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 0.3em;*/
  border: 0px none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <p>Popis položek, který je uveden u mzdových listů souhrnných (MLS), může vypadat např. takto:
    <br />&#160;
    <table class="B1-P4">
      <tr>
        <th class="seda">Název</th>
        <th class="seda">Popis </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="seda">SP základ celkem
          <br /><span class="FieldName">S_SocialInsBase</span></td>
        <td class="seda">Počítaná položka. Celkový základ SP vypočtený ze základů SP pro jednotlivé prac. poměry daného zaměstnance <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>......atd.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Tj. na nějakém vstupním formuláři souhrnného mzdového listu je položka "SP základ celkem". V programu je definována pod názvem <i>S_SocialInsBase</i> (a pod tímto názvem ji lze i vyhledat v programu i v helpu). Popis se odkazuje na položku dílčího
      mzdového listu "Základ SP" <i>(S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>. Jelikož se jedná o položku jiné agendy (jiného Business objektu), je uvedena i její zkratka, aby nedošlo k záměně, tj. <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add `position:absolute` which made it move out of the div having border.

```css
div.example
{
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0px;
    border-left: 4px solid #64c6ed;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

div.example::before
{
    content: 'Example';
    color: #64c6ed;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 0px none !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
                                                    <p>Popis položek, který je uveden u mzdových listů souhrnných (MLS), může vypadat např. takto:<br />&#160;<table class="B1-P4"><tr><th class="seda">Název</th><th class="seda">Popis </th></tr><tr><td class="seda">SP základ celkem<br /><span class="FieldName">S_SocialInsBase</span></td><td class="seda">Počítaná položka. Celkový základ SP vypočtený ze základů SP pro jednotlivé prac. poměry daného zaměstnance <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>......atd.</td></tr></table><p>Tj. na nějakém vstupním formuláři souhrnného mzdového listu je položka "SP základ celkem". V programu je definována pod názvem <i>S_SocialInsBase</i> (a pod tímto názvem ji lze i vyhledat v programu i v helpu). Popis se odkazuje na položku dílčího mzdového listu "Základ SP" <i>(S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>. Jelikož se jedná o položku jiné agendy (jiného Business objektu), je uvedena i její zkratka, aby nedošlo k záměně, tj. <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>.</p>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text outside the `.example` class.

Please check the below

```css
div.example
{
 font-size: 1em;
 /*letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 line-height: 1.5em;*/
 border: 0px;
 border-left: 4px solid #64c6ed;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 8px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h3
{
 color: #64c6ed;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 /*line-height: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 0.3em;*/
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
<div class="example">
  <p>Popis položek, který je uveden u mzdových listů souhrnných (MLS), může vypadat např. takto:<br />&#160;<table class="B1-P4"><tr><th class="seda">Název</th><th class="seda">Popis </th></tr><tr><td class="seda">SP základ celkem<br /><span class="FieldName">S_SocialInsBase</span></td><td class="seda">Počítaná položka. Celkový základ SP vypočtený ze základů SP pro jednotlivé prac. poměry daného zaměstnance <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>......atd.</td></tr></table><p>Tj. na nějakém vstupním formuláři souhrnného mzdového listu je položka "SP základ celkem". V programu je definována pod názvem <i>S_SocialInsBase</i> (a pod tímto názvem ji lze i vyhledat v programu i v helpu). Popis se odkazuje na položku dílčího mzdového listu "Základ SP" <i>(S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>. Jelikož se jedná o položku jiné agendy (jiného Business objektu), je uvedena i její zkratka, aby nedošlo k záměně, tj. <i>(MLD:S_SocialInsBaseCorrect)</i>.</p>
</div>
```